# What do you deliver for a website's UI?

Tags: usability, gui-design, design

What exactly do you have to deliver if you took on the task of creating a website's UI but without implementation?

Do you deliver a psd file with the design?

Answer (score 5):

What you mean by took a task? There must be expectation which comes along with it, right?

If it is without implementation, that can mean different things.

- **Low Fidelity Prototype or Wireframe**. This means you provide a sketchy, simple wireframe which will generally give the idea of the overall navigation of the website with a broad sense of controls being used on screen.
- **High Fidelity Prototype or your PSDs**. Here the design is more concrete. You showcase the visual design aspects like fonts, color palette, logos etc.
- **Interactive Prototype** can be the interlinking of the various screens and animations and gestures. This is deeper that high fidelity ones and you are close to start implementation.

In all the above stages, there are specific deliverables which can be expected from you. When you say without implementation, that can mean a range from BnW sketchy UI to a HTML mock up without hooking up to real data.

I guess you'd need to further clarify the expectations from your stakeholders.

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost, I think it's worth having a deeper conversation with the client about what's expected.  But if I had to take a guess, I'd do the following:

- Do a content audit for the site and produce an information architecture (IA) diagram and/or a mental model diagram (ref: "Mental Models" by Indi Young) to ensure I knew what content would support which needs and for which users.
- Design and document a "design system" for the site, including:

  - Common page components, and guidelines for creating more
  - Common page layout variations
- Produce some example layouts to support elements of the mental
  model/IA, ensuring that I focused on the following first:

  - Most frequently used layouts
  - More high profile content
  - More complex layouts

I'd also make it clear that each of those is a process which should involve the stakeholders.  You need to be very clear who the site is for, both in terms of a) *who's asking for it to be built* and the benefit *they* expect to have from it being built, and b) *who's expected to use it* and the benefit *those users* would expect to have from visiting it.

The whole process hinges on knowing both A and B - if neither you or your stakeholders know those things, then your design process needs to start with an exploration phase to find them out, which can then be written up and signed off as an agreement about what exactly you've been asked to.

If your stakeholders/clients are not already clear about that, I'd say that your first action needs to be to fix that problem and ensure everyone's expectations (including yours, which should include access to stakeholders) are understood.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're not looking for a view from an UX perspective, but a pure design perspective, as in just a web design, so the answers you might get here will be a bit overwhelming and confusing.

So, while I'd encourage you to follow UX best principles since they will help you and your clients, a basic set of deliverables for a pure UI approach would be

- UI Kit
- Vector Icons (if needed. SVG format is preferred)
- Fonts
- Images (remember they might be legal)
- Interaction Documentation (for example, what happens when a button is pressed, what happens if there's an animation, what happens with a popup or modal and so on)

But of course, this will also depend on your client's request and what you arrange with her. Generally speaking, a PSD won't be enough, but who knows... just ask your client and make sure to get as much insight from her as possible

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon clients, clients may ask you for PSD or may be JPEG format images.

And it is also depends how you work, if you follow any method of UX like Lean UX, then you have Wireframes, Visual Design and Clickable Prototypes to be deliver to the client.

Answer (score 0):

*How* you communicate design can vary depending on time, budget and tools. You can communicate your design using nothing more than pen or paper, or white board and sticky notes, or interactive design tools like Axure or Balsamiq, or general office tools like PowerPoint, Visio and Word. Or you can spend a lot of time creating something beautiful in Photoshop, or you can write html and css to create something interactive (this is easy if you use Bootstrap html/css).

My point is, there are many ways to communicate your design, and the way you communicate design will depend on a number of factors, including *your* skills at communication.